# How to find out which account my ASP.NET code is running under?

Tags: asp.net, security

I am getting an 'Access to the path is denied" error message when running in debug mode. I have tried granting permissions to {MACHINENAME}\ASPNET and to NETWORK SERVICE but this hasn't made any difference. I have also tried < impersonate = true /> using an admin account, this also made no difference. So how do I establish exactly which account is being used?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To find out which NT account your app is running under at any given time, do something like (in VB.NET):

```
    Dim User = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent.User
    Dim UserName = User.Translate(GetType(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).Value
```

When using ASP.NET, this account will match the identity of the application pool, which you configure using IIS Manager. Note that the anonymous IIS user isn't much involved with ASP.NET requests.

Answer (score 15):

C# Code for the vb.net answer

```
var user = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User;
var userName = user.Translate(typeof (System.Security.Principal.NTAccount));
```

Answer (score 8):

You could use this code:

**C#**

```
Response.Write("Windows Account which runs ASP.NET is: " 
   + Environment.Username);
```

**VB.NET**

```
Response.Write("Windows Account which runs ASP.NET is: " _
   & Environment.Username)
```

If you run your application in Visual Studio on your PC (localhost) you'll get your user name. If you deploy ASP.NET web application on IIS, you will probably get the NETWORK SERVICE account, because that is default user running IIS 6.0 (ASPNET on Windows Server 2000's IIS 5.0).

`Environment.UserName` returns the thread's currently logged-on user. `Page.User` returns the name that ASP.NET verifies through Authentication and this user in most cases is independent of the Windows logon that is running the current thread. For anonymous requests Page.User is blank, while Environment.User will be NETWORK SERVICE.

*As [mdb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8562/mdb) correctly points out in a comment to this answer, Environment.Username will simply return the USERNAME environment variable, which is set on process creation and not updated in case of impersonation and such.*

Comment: Do keep in mind, though, that Environment.Username will simply return the USERNAME environment variable, which is set on process creation and not updated in case of impersonation and such.

Answer (score -3):

```
strint t=System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser().UserName.ToString();
```

Comment: For the benefit of future readers can you add some text to explain why this answer is preferable to the older ones?

Comment: This doesn't work. This returns the username of the logged in user - not the username of the executing user of the web application, which is what the OP asked for.