# What user is my app using to access the file system?

Tags: asp.net, security, iis

I have an application that is getting a `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` error when it tries to read from the file system.

I looked at the app pool and I see that is using `Network Service` for it's identity.  The IIS application is allowing anonymous authentication using an existing account, lets call it `IUSR-MYSERVER`.  It also has `Integrated Windows authentication` enabled.

If I go to the folder in question and Add `Everyone` with Read+Execute permissions the error goes away.  But if I add `IUSR-MYSERVER` or `NETWORK SERVICE` with the same permissions, I still get the same error.

When I look at the error's entry in my Event Log it has the User as `N/A`.

What user is my application trying to access the file system as?  I assume it would be bad to just use `Everyone`?

Comment: which version of IIS are you using ?

Comment: to use IUSR I add this line in my web.config : <identity impersonate="true"/>

Comment: @EmeraldCoder, is there a way I could just figure out what user it is currently running as?

Comment: if you just want to know what user is running you can look at this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275824/how-to-find-out-which-account-my-asp-net-code-is-running-under

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the web application uses impersonation, then the file would be accessed by the currently logged in user (or IUSR for anonymous users) - using Integrated Windows Authentication and IE would result in single sign on so the user opening the browser would be accessing the file.

If the impersonation is not used, then application pool identity is used.

To determine the currently logged in user in code, use `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name` - but note that this does not represent the account which is accessing the file.

To determine the actual identity under which the code is executing, use `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`.