# Access is denied when trying to open an exe application from a website

Tags: asp.net, exe

In my website, I tried to open a windows application (.exe) upon a button click. But it showing "Access is denied".

Stack trace:

```
[Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied]
   System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo) +614
   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() +56
   ghs.btnTry_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\vhosts\ddrivestudio.com\httpdocs\tanishq\ghs.aspx.cs:19
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +111
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +110
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565
```

Button click event:

```
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = Request.MapPath("~/App/App1.exe");
    p.Start();
```

Comment: Can you post your code (button_click)?

Answer (score 0):

Hope the following links already have an answer.
Reference:
1.[Which permissions are required to enable process.start via asp.net application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15000265/which-permissions-are-required-to-enable-process-start-via-asp-net-application)
2. [Access is denied at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6314173/access-is-denied-at-system-diagnostics-process-startwithcreateprocessprocesssta)