# Asp.net Access Denied to path from another app pool folder

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I have two different application on IIS 7.5. I would like to move file Application one to application two.

For instance:
User upload file in Application One and The system have to move the file to Application Two. However i meet Access denied problem. I know it's normal. But how can i handle it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Each application runs under some pool, and each pool runs under some account.

Find that accounts and set the write permissions to the directories that you like to access.
Eg from App1, if run under Account1, give to the directories that you wish to been able to write, permissions to Account1.

This code can help you to find the running acount:

```
var user = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User;
var userName = user.Translate(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount));
```

Reference : [How to find out which account my ASP.NET code is running under?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275824/how-to-find-out-which-account-my-asp-net-code-is-running-under)

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I have read this topic before and i wasn't success. I see user:S-1-5-17 and username:NT AUTHORITY\IUSR when i use these code and i didn't add these accounts because these account not found. Where am i doing wrong?

Comment: Ignore the `S-1-5-17...` and focus to the `NT AUTHORITY\IUSR`, this is a user on the `NT AUTHORITY` computer with the name `IUSR`, this account exist 100% :)